# Multiple templated variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I would like to use two templated parameter packs but I do not know how to do it. I read a lot of other StackOverflow posts but not one with templated parameter pack.

```
template < template < unsigned int > class... EntityList >
struct Entities{};

template < template < unsigned int > class... EntityBuilderList >
struct EntityBuilders{};

template < unsigned int dim, template < unsigned int > class... T >
class CompleteBuilder;

template < unsigned int dim, template < unsigned int > class... EntityList, 
    template < unsigned int > class... EntityBuilderList >
class CompleteBuilder< dim, Entities< EntityList...>, EntityBuilders< EntityBuilderList...> >
    : public EntityBuilderList< dim >...
{};
```

Then, I would  like to use it like `CompleteBuilder< 3, Entities< A, B, C >, EntityBuilders< Ab, Bb, Cb > > builder`. But I have this error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<unsigned int dim, template<unsigned int <anonymous> > class ... T> class CompleteBuilder’
 class CompleteBuilder< dim, Entities< EntityList...>, EntityBuilders< EntityBuilderList...> >
                                                                                                            ^
note:   expected a class template, got ‘Entities<EntityList ...>’
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the specialization you have of `CompleteBuilder`; your primary template needs to be defined like this

```
template <unsigned int dim, class... T>
class CompleteBuilder;
```

Comment: Thanks! Can this class be a friend from another one? `class Foo{template <unsigned int, class...> friend class CompleteBuilder};`

Comment: @ABotella - yes, it can